# Recursively determine whether elements in array can sum to target - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

I am doing practice with recursion and trying small problems. One of the functions I am trying to design `comboSum` takes in an array of integers, its size, and a target value. It returns true if a combination of any of the elements (can only use each element once) adds to the target value. This is my implementation so far.

```
// Expected Behaviors
// comboSum([1, 2, 3], 3, 0) => false
// comboSum([2, 4, 8], 3, 12) => true
// comboSum([2, 4, 8], 3, 11) => false
// comboSum([], 0, 0) => true

bool comboSum(const int a[], int size, int target)
{
    if (target == 0)
        return true; // if we have decremented target to zero
    if (target != 0 && size == 0)
        return false; // if we havent hit target to zero and we have no more elements

    size--;

    return (comboSum(a, size, target) || comboSum(a, size, target - a[size]));

    // OR logic ensures that even if just one sum exists, this returns true
}
```

My algorithm works except for the case of an array with all non-zero values and the target being zero. The function immediately returns true without checking for a valid summation.

```
// comboSum({1, 2, 3}, 3, 0) returns true when this should be false
```

What are some possible ways to correct this issue?

**Edit:** I cannot change the parameters or call any additional helper functions. The function header must remain as is and I must solve the problem recursively (no use of for or while loops or STL algorithms)

Comment: So taking nothing shouldn't be a valid option? You could just add a special check for this. Wrap your recursive function in another function that is only called once at the beginning and triggers the recursive calls, and add the check there.

Comment: You might also want a test case with negative values, and negative targets.

Comment: I'm also curious what the algorithm constraints are--if the target is 0, we can certainly choose 0 elements that sum to it, which the last test case seems to imply. And good point @Peter regarding negative values.

Comment: Combo sum of any two elements can be simple, however taking all n combination probability to  sum up to give the target value may be more challenging one.

Comment: I think that is correct behavior. If you select zero elements from the array, the sum is zero. Since this looks like a homework problem, I'd double-check with your professor to double-check that case.

Comment: @PasserBy That part of the code is correct; see the `size--` right before the `return`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to keep the `size` parameter fixed and have another parameter that indicates the current position of the recursion.

```
bool comboSum(const int *a, int size, int pos, int target) {
    if (target == 0)
        return pos < size || size == 0; // true if pos has moved or if the array is empty
    else if (pos == 0)
        return false;

    pos--;
    return comboSum(a, size, pos, target) || comboSum(a, size, pos, target - a[pos]);
}
```

This solution handles your test cases correctly, but we have to pass the `pos` argument after the `size` argument. Both arguments should start with the same value:

```
// comboSum([1, 2, 3], 3, 3, 0) => false
// comboSum([2, 4, 8], 3, 3, 12) => true
// comboSum([2, 4, 8], 3, 3, 11) => false
// comboSum([], 0, 0, 0) => true
```

### C++ in Practice

Since this question is tagged as C++, it would be a good idea to use a class that gives us more flexibility than C arrays. For example, we could use a `std::vector`. If that's the case, then we don't need an extra parameter for the size of the list:

```
#include <vector>

bool comboSum(std::vector<int>& v, size_t pos, int target)
{
    if (target == 0) {
        return pos < v.size() || v.size() == 0;
    } else if (pos == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    pos--;
    return comboSum(v, pos, target) || comboSum(v, size, target - v[pos]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep everything you have as-is, try adding a variable to count the number of recursions.

```
bool comboSum(const int a[], int size, int target, int count = 0)
{
    if (target == 0 && size == 0 && count == 0)
        return false;
    else if (target == 0)
       return true;
    else if (target != 0 && size == 0)
       return false;

size--;

return (comboSum(a, size, target) || comboSum(a, size, target - a[size]));
};
```

Please note that there are definitely better ways to do this, but as a learning exercise it doesn't hurt to give this a go!

Comment: Your code doesn't handle correctly one of the test cases mentioned by the OP, which is comboSum([], 0, 0) => true. Your code would return false in that case.

Comment: Shoot, you're right. That's what I get for trying to answer questions when I can't sleep. Sorry!